# what are the .h~ files after gcc compilings/linkings?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, ubuntu, compiler-construction

After compiling/linking some .c .cpp and .h files, there are a couple of extra .h~ files show up. They seem to have the exact content of the original .h files, when I peek at them using cat.
BTW, the OS is ubuntu

Comment: These are probably produced by you text editor, not by gcc.

Comment: you might as well see them before compiling ;)

Comment: aha, you are right. seems to be from gedit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The are backup files produced by text editors, notably emacs and gedit, among others.  See [How do I control how emacs makes backup files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151945/how-do-i-control-how-emacs-makes-backup-files) for tips on controlling that.

Comment: Also, Thank you and leftaroundabout. As leftaroundabout pointed out, it's from the editor I was using, gedit.