# Java meaning of .java~

Tags: java, tilde

By typing `jar -tf myJar.jar MyProject` I get in the file list, besides the normal `.java` and `.class` files, also a `.java~` file.
I have read googling it around that it is due to some other incomplete version of the `file.java`. If so, How can I go ahead and remove those files? since in the real folder there are no other files than file.java and file.class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could they be back up files of somekind ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They're almost certainly just backup files automatically created by whatever text editor you're using. You should be fine to remove them.

I'm sure they *are* in the real folder - it's possible your shell/explorer is hiding them from you. Just try using a command line to remove them by name, even if they don't show up on autocomplete.

(It's hard to be more specific when we don't know which editor you're using, which operating system, or how you're looking at the directory...)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt response!

Answer (score 2):

Those are vim backup files. See [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Remove_swap_and_backup_files_from_your_working_directory) and [here](http://scratching.psybermonkey.net/2011/02/vim-how-to-stop-vim-creating-tilde.html) for some configuration options to avoid cluttering up your working directories.

Comment: It can also be emacs backup files. How to remove them : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151945/how-do-i-control-how-emacs-makes-backup-files

Comment: Or backup files from a number of other editors. `gedit` for example does the same. I guess it's a common file name convention on Unix-like operating systems for backup files.