# C++ in Linux creates 2 files

Tags: c++, linux

I created a C++ file, `adjacent_find.cpp` in a directory, using `g++`, I compiled it successfully and an output file was generated. When I list the content of the directory from the terminal, I see three files:

```
Linux-Host:~/Desktop/Algorithms/algorithm # ls
adjacent_find.cpp    adjacent_find.cpp~    output
```

What is the purpose and meaning of the file with the tilde (`~`)?  I can only see the file with the tilde (`~`) from the terminal, it is not displayed in my file browser.

Comment: Could it be your editor creating a backup file each time you save?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I control how Emacs makes backup files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151945/how-do-i-control-how-emacs-makes-backup-files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files ending with `~` is actually a snapshot of the oriinal file before it was saved. So basically, they're backups, and you can safely delete them if you want to.

And these are not created by g++. They are created by the text editor.

Comment: Appreciate your assistance.