# How to configure Emacs to save backup for files under temp directory?

Tags: emacs, configuration, backup

I use emacsclient to edit temp files in /tmp a lot and would like to create backup copies of my files automatically like we do with other files. I'm sure there is a way to do it - but how? :)

(I searched the Emacs manual, emacswiki and SO but couldn't find anything useful)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the `normal-backup-enable-predicate` function, which is the default value for the `backup-enable-predicate` variable.

As the sole purpose of the default function is to inhibit backups for files in various temporary directories, you may just want to set a replacement which returns `t` unconditionally.

```
(setq backup-enable-predicate (lambda (name) t))
```

The usage in files.el suggests to me that you could also just set this variable to `nil`. That's not stated in the documentation, so it might not be reliable, but the variable isn't referenced by any other library in Emacs, so it's *probably* fine (but I'd still recommend using the lambda, because it's more obvious what that's doing).

See also <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Making Backups` <kbd>RET</kbd>

n.b. I'm not actually familiar with `small-temporary-file-directory` (see the docstring for that variable), but the `temporary-file-directory` value would typically be `/tmp/`, so those two cases are usually the same.

If you did want to retain the default behaviour for some temporary directories but not others, you should define a modified copy of the original function: `(defun my-backup-enable-predicate ...)` and then `(setq backup-enable-predicate 'my-backup-enable-predicate)`

Comment: I think we have a winner here. The Emacs manual actually mentioned `backup-enable-predicate' - which I somehow missed. :( Thanks!

Comment: What if the files in temporary-file-directory are immediately removed after I quit emacsclient? How can I make a copy of the file before killing the buffer?

Comment: Answering my own question - seems I'll need "C-u C-u C-x C-s" http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Backup.html

Answer (score 0):

Stick this in yer .emacs file:

```
;; create an invisible backup directory so our directories 
;; look a bit cleaner
;; thanks to #emacs in irc.freenode.org, Ryan Barrett of snarfed.org
;; and freethegnu.wordpress.com
 (defun make-backup-file-name (filename)
 (defvar backups-dir "/tmp/")
 (make-directory backups-dir t)
 (expand-file-name
 (concat backups-dir (file-name-nondirectory filename) "~")
 (file-name-directory filename)))
```

Comment: Would be nice if the backup is saved to home directory like "~/.backup" even for edits in /tmp (for example /tmp/tmp.1234).

Comment: Lester Cheung: that would be `(setq backup-directory-alist '(("." . "~/.backup")))` but please read through the various answers to [How do I control how Emacs makes backup files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151945/how-do-i-control-how-emacs-makes-backup-files) because this is unlikely to be the only option you'll want to configure.

Comment: Thanks @phils yes that's what I'm using at the moment.