# Weird generated files from Emacs

Tags: emacs

I find that there are a lot of files like the one below generated by Emacs. What are those files ? And is there anyone that I can put them in one place and stop hanging around in the project ?

```
app/helpers/#application_helper.rb#
```

Thanks

Comment: see http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Save-Files.html#Auto-Save-Files

Comment: @ymonad thanks for the documentation. It answers my question, please put the comment as an answer. I will mark it as an accepted one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These files are automatically saved versions of files edited by Emacs.  You can tell Emacs to put all auto-save files and all backup files (those ending on `~`) in one place by adding this to your `.emacs`  or `.emacs.d/init.el` file:

```
(setq backup-directory-alist
      `((".*" . ,(expand-file-name
             (concat user-emacs-directory "backups"))))
(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms
      `((".*" ,(expand-file-name
             (concat user-emacs-directory "backups") t)))
```

This will set the directory to be `~/.emacs.d/backups/`.  Another common thing to do is setting the directory to the temp directory:

```
(setq backup-directory-alist
      `((".*" . ,temporary-file-directory)))
(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms
      `((".*" ,temporary-file-directory t)))
```

Alternatively, you could completely disable auto-saving but this is not recommended.

**EDIT:** I just found this related question with lots of advice on how to configure this behaviour: [How do I control how Emacs makes backup files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151945/how-do-i-control-how-emacs-makes-backup-files)