# Emacs M-x shell creates unwanted C:\tmp directory

Tags: windows, bash, shell, emacs, cygwin

I am using Emacs-24.3 (and won't upgrade).  Running the M-x shell command spuriously creates an unwanted C:\tmp directory.  Yes, I am running on Windows (with Cygwin).  I've turned off the .emacs start-up as well as killed my .bashrc to isolate this effect to the M-x shell command.  I have no TMP or TEMP environment variables that specify C:\TMP, so I think it's default Unix behavior of using /tmp as the std system temp file dir.

In any case, I don't want this behavior on Windows (although I am willing to do whatever it takes to redirect useful behavior somewhere else, e.g. C:\WINDOWS\TEMP).

What do I have to do to suppress creation of this unwanted directory?

(Thanks in advance!)

Comment: If you set the variable `shell-file-name` to some other program, such as `/usr/bin/true`, does the directory still get created? I had a look at the source code for the `shell` command, and didn't find anything that would create the directory, so I just wanted to rule out the shell completely.

Comment: @legoscia Thanks for that helpful suggestion.  So it is not a Emacs nor M-x shell problem: this is bash behavior to create C:\TMP.  I have defined TMPDIR to make it use the windows location but it still goes ahead and creates C:\TMP.  :(  I'll solve this as a bash problem or open another question in SO with bash as topic.  Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few suggestions:

Control your temporary-file-directory environment setting

or look at the TEMP part of:
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/General-Variables.html

TEMP
These environment variables are used to initialize the variable temporary-file-directory, which specifies a directory in which to put temporary files (see Backup). Emacs tries to use TMPDIR first. If that is unset, Emacs normally falls back on /tmp, but on MS-Windows and MS-DOS it instead falls back on TMP, then TEMP, and finally c:/temp.

Or look at:
[How do I control how Emacs makes backup files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151945/how-do-i-control-how-emacs-makes-backup-files)