# Emacs automated Backup: Filename+DATE.org

Tags: emacs, backup, filenames

I am writing on a novel in Org Mode and I fear that at some point wide parts will be erased by me without noticing, therefore I want Emacs to automatically create backup files.

Google suggested different solutions for this issue which I am unfortunately not able to bring together (just started emacs half year ago, its hard to interpret the codes, and harder to write myself).

What I am trying to do:

example.org (backuping today)

- should be saved every x Hours or xxxx keystrokes
- Backups should therefore be named "example 17.6.15 11:35.org"
- In addition if possible: Delete all files but 1 of every day at the end of the week.

Is there maybe a Package with this features? (Is there another solution outside Emacs?)

I guess the following links looked promising:

- http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/backup-each-save.el
- [How do I control how Emacs makes backup files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151945/how-do-i-control-how-emacs-makes-backup-files)

Comment: It's certainly *possible* to do this with Emacs, but I think using a proper [Revision Control System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) or possibly a [backup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_backup_software) tool that supports incremental or differential backups would be much better.

Comment: Good advice above. Specifically with org-mode, look at the settings `org-ctrl-k-protect-subtree` and `org-catch-invisible-edits`, which you can access through `customize-variables`. These help prevent you accidentally deleting large chunks of text.

Comment: I like the idea of a Revision Control System, nonetheless I am eager to know the solution within emacs. Using as less tools as needed has its beauty.