# How to recover a deleted racket file from DrRacket?

Tags: racket, dr.racket

I recently (yesterday) finished up a somewhat large project that added up to almost 2300 lines of code. It was all in racket using the Dr.Racket IDE. I saved up the project, closed my laptop, and went on with my day. Later on, I opened my laptop, added a few things to the project, **did not save**, and closed the lid on my laptop. Put in hibernation mode.

I open up my laptop again to actually submit the assignment because it was due that night and find that it had shut down. I don't know why it shut down because I certainly did not shut it down... maybe low on battery. I open it up, login and everything, and I find Dr. Racket telling me that it has my project that I could recover. I was like sweet, clicked the button, and then it gave me an error saying that it could not find my project.

Skip to after 30 minutes of searching desperately for my project.. I ascertained its disappearance. It was just totally gone... 100%. Just.. **poof**.

I am asking for some sort of explanation. Maybe not so much a solution because I know those are just... not possible most likely. But I want to know if any of you guys know how it could have just dissappeared. I checked the recycling bin, tmp files, I checked the folder it had been in and every other folder in my laptop to be honest. Just.. **poof**.

Comment: For a fast answer, try the racket user mailing list.

Comment: Where can I find the mailing list?

Comment: https://lists.racket-lang.org/

Comment: This is just a suggestion, but you might consider using Emacs which features periodic auto-saving and the creation of backup files, both of which can be configured (there's a good SO question about that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151945/how-do-i-control-how-emacs-makes-backup-files)). There is also [racket-mode](https://github.com/greghendershott/racket-mode) and [geiser](https://github.com/jaor/geiser) for Emacs which both work well with Racket.

Comment: just happened to me too. clicked recover... now file is blank! -- will definitely stick to vim for any serious work :/